# CSS underline disappears when opacity is used

Tags: css

In current stable Chrome, when using the following CSS where some opacity is set, the underline on the text disappears. When the opacity is set to 1 or removed, the underline shows fine. Help please? Thanks!

```css
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P');
p {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
  text-decoration: underline;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: it happens only with your font-family, it's fine with the default ones

Comment: According to Google, a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282132/setting-css-opacity-removes-underline) was asked 3 hours ago but the author deleted the post. Strange coincidence.

Comment: @JosephWebbern same guy - probably deleted as no code snippet was provided so question was downvoted - hard to get those removed so easier to delete question and ask a new one

Comment: Yes, when my question was downvoted into oblivion and apparently wrongly formulated I deleted it (funny how StackOverflow on their blog seems to care so much about a welcoming space, yet their framework does a lot to counter that :)). A few hours later, I encountered the issue again, and spend some more time to create a JSFiddle... and realized the font may be a crucial part in the mix.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `opacity` you should set `color` with the CSS [`rgba()`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp) function:

```css
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P');
p {
  font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works for this example and some of my uses! Is there also a generic solution that works for more complex examples which require inheritance of the color of the wrapper? For instance, in our project we have class ".pseudoLink" which we're using in many places, and in some of those places we're setting an opacity on the link... but don't necessarily want to re-set the color, but just inherit it instead (or vice versa, when we're setting the color but not opacity). Thanks!